# Realm query with child arrays

Tags: android, realm

Here's the Object I'm working with:

```
public class NavigationMenuModule extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey
    public String sectionKey;

    public RealmList<ItemModule> modules;
    public RealmList<Article> spotlightSponsored;
    public RealmList<Article> items;
}
```

The child Article Object:

```
public class Article extends RealmObject {
        @PrimaryKey
        public String contentId;
        public String leadImageURL;
        public String summary;
        public String headline;
    }
```

How would I structure this realm call:

1. get **NavigationMenuModule** item by sectionKey
2. get **spotlightSponsored** within that **NavigationMenuModule** that matches the article's contentId

The method below works but I feel like there's probably a "neater" way:

```
public static Article getArticle(String sectionKey, String articleId) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    NavigationMenuModule navigationMenuModule = realm.where(NavigationMenuModule.class).equalTo("sectionKey", sectionKey).findFirst();
    if (navigationMenuModule != null && !navigationMenuModule.spotlightSponsored.isEmpty()) {
        for (Article article : navigationMenuModule.spotlightSponsored) {
            if (article.getContentId().equals(articleId)) {
                Article ret = realm.copyFromRealm(article);
                realm.close();
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
    realm.close();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Code for `Article` class is missing from this question.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce  Oops, doing it now.  It's a very simple subClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically this should work with Realm 3.5.0

```
public class NavigationMenuModule extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {   
    @PrimaryKey
    public String sectionKey;

    public RealmList<ItemModule> modules;
    public RealmList<Article> spotlightSponsored;
    public RealmList<Article> items;
}

public class Article extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    public String contentId;
    public String leadImageURL;
    public String summary;
    public String headline;

    @LinkingObjects("spotlightSponsored")
    public final RealmResults<NavigationMenuModule> spotlightSponsoredOf = null;

    @LinkingObjects("items")
    public final RealmResults<NavigationMenuModule> itemsOf = null;
}

public static Article getArticle(Realm realm, String sectionKey, String articleId) {    
    return realm.where(Article.class)
                .equalTo("contentId", articleId)
                .equalTo("spotlightSponsoredOf.sectionKey", sectionKey)
                .findFirst();
}
```

Comment: can you please provide some explanation with this answer?  Sorry, I'm new to realm and trying to get up to speed with it

Comment: I added inverse relationships (backlinks) to `Article` then did a query using Realm's Query API, also I expect Realm to be provided to the method so that you don't need to copy it from the Realm which is typically an indicator of misusing/misunderstanding the API (unless you want to serialize with GSON or make it modifiable outside a transaction, like in a form). If you can show the answer that you got the idea from, I'll downvote it for being a bad answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't get that snippet from anywhere, I am working through it myself :)

Comment: Well, `copyFromRealm()` is generally not needed, although Realm assumes that you'll make use of the `RealmChangeListener` API. I recommend accepting the answer only after you've verified that it works, though!

Comment: We're considering adding a "wasRead" Boolean that would be flipped to true when the article is clicked. That's why I have the copyFromRealm in there

Comment: In that case I understand it even less, if you modify the object in a transaction from any thread and you use RealmChangeListener to update your adapter / view then the UI (which is "was read") will automatically reflect the state in the db where Realm manages the change notifications

Comment: I thought you can't change a value in an object returned from a query and that you had to do copyFromRealm to do so

Comment: You **can** modify the object's values ***inside a transaction***. Although generally you go to a background thread, open a Realm, call execute transaction, query the object by ID inside transaction, modify the object inside transaction, close realm